# what can cause a ftp file upload to fail in a working ftp setup?

Tags: rhel, ftp

We have a system where files are processed and uploaded on another server.
I found that one of the uploads failed out of 1000 uploads.
size is not an issue since there is sufficient space available.
the file size was of 75076168 bytes but only 75076157 bytes was uploaded and got the error message can't put the file in logs.

just wondering if there is a connection loss of network does ftp resumes the upload where it left of or there could be some kind of tcp packet transfer/assembling failure.

Comment: And did you gather some logs and examine them?

Comment: sorry, i will check if i can get access to the server logs